# How can I reinitialize a React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I have a page where I display the data from the API based on an id. I am using React Query to manage the storage of the data. What I am trying to do is when the input with the id is changed I'd like to refetch the data for a different object. I tried to do the following:

```
const useData = (id: string) => useQuery(
  ['data', id],
  () => axios.get(`/api/data/${id}`),
  {
    enabled: !!id,
  },
);

const Page = () => {
  const [id, setID] = useState('1');
  const [result, setResult] = useState(useData(id));

  useEffect(() => {
    setResult(useData(id));
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      {result.data}
      <input onChange={(e) => setID(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

But you cannot call hooks inside the useEffect callback. What would be the correct approach for me to reset the `result` with the data from a new API call?

Comment: Why are you putting `useData` as the initial value of `useState`? It seems like the `useState` is unnecessary and leading to issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-query will automatically refetch if parts of the query key change. So you are on the right track regarding your custom hook, and for your `App`, it also becomes much simpler:

```
const useData = (id: string) => useQuery(
  ['data', id],
  () => axios.get(`/api/data/${id}`),
  {
    enabled: !!id,
  },
);

const Page = () => {
  const [id, setID] = useState('1');
  const result = useData(id);

  return (
    <div>
      {result.data}
      <input onChange={(e) => setID(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

that's it. that's all you need.

if id changes, the query key changes, thus giving you a new cache entry, which react-query will fetch for you.

Comment: Thanks a million, still can't quite wrap my head around the inner workings of hooks, but really loving React Query.